# Python Style: nested vs extra function

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python (2.7) and have a question about what's the most Pythonic way to do something; my code (part of a class) Looks like this (a somewhat naive Version):

```
def calc_pump_height(self):
    for i in range(len(self.primary_)):
        for j in range(len(self.primary_)):
            if self.connections_[i][j].sub_kind_ in [1,4]:
                self.calc_spec_pump_height(i,j)

def calc_spec_pump_height(self,i,j):
    pass
```

(obviously pass will be replaced by something else, manipulating attributes of the object of this class, without generating a return value)

I'd like to ask how I should do this: I could avoid the second function and write the extra code directly into the first function, getting rid of one function (Simple is better than complex), but creating a heavily nested function at the same time (Flat is better than nested).

I could also create some sort of list comprehension to avoid using a double Loop, eg:

```
def calc_pump_height(self):
    ra = range(len(self.primary_))
    [self.calc_spec_pump_height(i,j) for i,j in zip(ra, ra)]
```

(I'd have to move the if condition into the 2nd function; this would also create a null-list but I don't care about this, since `calc_spec_pump_height` is supposed to manipulate the object, not return something useful)

In essence: I'm iterating over a 2D list, testing each object for a certain characteristic and then do something with that object.

Which of the above methods is 'the best'? Or is there another way that I'm missing?

Comment: IMHO, the second way looks a lot cleaner, but it might just be me...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do some of your attributes end with a _? In Python, if you're tying to indicate that something is private to that class, you generally put an underscore at the beginning, not the end.

Comment: @Ben: You're absolutely right, and I'm aware of this now. This is actually part of a piece of code I wrote when I first started to use Python, I'm currently rewritting it but haven't come round to renaming the variables (the original idea was to distinguish between local and class variables. In Python this is (apart from violating the standard) redundant due to the 'self.' . In my other projects (eg: programming microcontrollers) it wasn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing about functions/methods is that they should do one thing.

`calc_pump_height` implements two things: It finds elements in a 2D list that match some criteria, and then it calculates a value for each of those elements. It's ok for its purpose to be combining the other two operations, if that makes sense for the object's public API, but its not ok for it to *implement* either or both.

- Finding the elements that match the criteria is a discrete step; that should be a function.
- Calculating your value is clearly a discrete step; that should be a function.

I would implement the element matcher as a (private) generator, that takes the test condition as an argument, and yields all matching elements. It's just an iterator over your data structure, masked by the logical test. You can wrap that in a named public method called `get_1_4_subkinds()` or something that makes more sense in your domain. That generalises the code and gives you the flexibility to implement other conditions in the future. Also, your i and j are tightly coupled, so it makes sense to pass them around as a single concept. Then your code becomes:

```
def calc_pump_height(self):
    for subkind_indices in self.get_1_4_subkinds():
        self.calc_pump_spec_height(subkind_indices)
```

Comment: Interesting point, I have not considered it that way, but it would definitely come in handy later on, thanks! And also you have a point that it makes sense to split it up because the two parts do seperate things...

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood “simplicity”:

> write the extra code directly into the first function, getting rid of one function (Simple is better than complex)

That's not simple. Breaking complex sequences into discrete, focussed functions *increases* simplicity.

In that light, I would say that yes, you should definitely prefer `calc_spec_pump_height` as a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate one level of nesting in your first function by using `itertools.product`  to generate your `i` and `j` values at the same time (`itertools.product(range(len(self.primary_)), repeat=2)`. The `zip` you use in the your second version won't work correctly, it will only yield identical pairs, `0,0`, `1,1`, `2,2`, etc.

As for the overall design, you should not use a list comprehension if you don't care about the return value from the function you're calling. Use an explicit loop when it's the looping you want (rather than a list of computed values).

If there's a non-trivial amount of code that will go in `calc_spec_pump_height`, it makes perfect sense to make it as a separate method. If it's a one or two liner, then it might be OK to inline within `calc_pump_height`, but that method's loops and condition testing may be complicated enough already to justify factoring out the inner part of the algorithm.

You should usually think about splitting a big function up when it is too long to fit onto a single screen in your editor. That is about the limit of how many details (variable names, etc.) we can keep in our mind simultaneously.  On the other hand, you shouldn't waste time (either your own programming time or function call overhead at run time) by factoring out every little piece of every problem. Factor part of a function out if you're using it from more than one place, or if you can't keep the details of the whole function in your head at once otherwise.

So, other than the (marginal) improvement of `itertools.product` and given the limited information you've provided about what `calc_spec_pump_height` will do, I think your code is already about as good as it can get!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and giving some 'benchmarks' for length of functions etc